# MongoDB Shell - Pass a text file through insert command

Tags: mongodb, shell

I am working on mongoDb on shell
i want to insert a document

```
{
title: "MyName",
Job: "MyJob"
}
```

How ever inserting a long document is hectic on shell.
Is there anyway that i can make a text file and insert it in the collection?

Somehow like

```
db.collectionname.insert(filepath);
```

Comment: Use `mongoimport`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!